# DSP Audio Function Block to Audio Output

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, simulink

I have a simulink block which takes a function from matlab and takes the output of that as an input to the "To Audio Device" diagram. The error I get with this is Port Audio: Invalid number of channels..So I added the variable H to record audio with the DSP.AudioRecorder, but I can't set that as an output  H = fcn() .. So main question is what's the simplest way to do this because I'm pretty lost right now. Thanks!

The following code I have is:

```
 function y = fcn()
 %#codegen
 Fs = 125;      %# Samples per second
 toneFreq = 50;  %# Tone frequency, in Hertz
 nSeconds = 2;   %# Duration of the sound
 y = sin(linspace(0, nSeconds*toneFreq*2*pi, round(nSeconds*Fs)));

coder.extrinsic('sound');
coder.extrinsic('audiowrite');

H = dsp.AudioRecorder('DeviceName','Default', 'SampleRate', 48000, 'BufferSizeSource',       'Property', 'BufferSize', 512, 'NumChannels', 2);
step(H);

sound(y, Fs);  %# Play sound at sampling rate Fs

audiowrite(y, Fs, 8, 'tone_50Hz.wav');  %# Save as an 8-bit, 1 kHz signal
```

Answer (score 0):

"To Audio Device" block considers each column as a channel. You should transpose your data y before returning as output from fcn.

Currently you are getting the error because you have a row vector as y and each sample in this row vector is being considered a separate channel.